# Function Equivalent to a Constant Paradox

Tags: calculus, functions

Say I define $z(x,y) = x^2+y = \text{constant}$

Then $\left(\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)_{y} = 2x$

However, $\left(\dfrac{\partial \text{ constant}}{\partial x}\right)_y = 0$

Shouldn't $\left(\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)_{y}$ = $\left(\dfrac{\partial \text{ constant}}{\partial x}\right)_{y}\text{ ?}$

Comment: If $x^2+y$ is constant, then you can't hold $y$ fixed while you vary $x$.

Comment: So I placed a constraint in after calculating the original derivative which violated it i.e. dz/dx is nonzero before constraint and zero afterwards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you say $x^2+y=\text{constant}$, you're defining a curve in the $xy$-plane, which is a parabola $y=-x^2+\text{constant}$.  If you move along that curve, both $x$ and $y$ are changing.  But if you write $z=y^2+x$, defining $z$ as a function of those two variables, both of which can vary freely, then the expression $\partial z/\partial x$ means the rate of change of $z$ with respect to $x$ when $y$ is fixed.

**But $y$ is *not* fixed if you move along the parabola.**

Suppose you regard $z$ as depending on $x$ and $y$, and $x$ and $y$ as depending on $w$ in such a way that $y=-w^2+\text{constant}$ and $x=w$.  Then you can apply a chain rule:
$$
\frac{\partial z}{\partial w} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{\partial x}{\partial w} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{\partial y}{\partial w} = 2x\cdot1+1\cdot(-2w) = 2w-2w
$$
and then you see that the derivative is $0$, as you'd expect since $z=\text{constant}$.

Comment: Do you mean x = w ?

Comment: @Ned : Correct.  Typo fixed.